# why doesn't my App ID appear in .config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to follow the directions in https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity. The directions say to install the extension in Chrome and then go to the directory in config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions that matches the install extension's app ID. But my app ID's directory  doesn't appear in config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions. This is strange since the extension is clearly evident in the browser.I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Could this be an Ubuntu problem?

Comment: Unpacked extensions loaded in developer mode aren't copied from their original folder.

Comment: So what's the recommendation? Pack it first and then continue? Or turn off developer mode while I continue?

Comment: Unpacked extensions can't be used with the identity API. You need to upload it to the web store, AFAIK.